# Сравнение значение с БД

Tags: php, yii2, парсер

При написании парсера мне нужно сравнивать есть ли уже такой url в базе и если нет то спарсить его а потом контент по этой ссылке. Пробую использовать exist с базовой комплектации Yii2 но походу получается какой то индусско-китайский неработающий код. Не работает у меня exist должным образом. Может кто подскажет как его правильно использовать.

```
            foreach ($links_get as $link_get){
            $url = pq($link_get)->find('.titles h3 a')->attr('href');
            if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0) {
                $site_url = $url;
            } else{
                $site_url = $site . $url;
            }
            if(!News::find()->where( [ 'url' => $site_url ] )->exists())
            {
                $img = pq($link_get)->find('img')->attr('src');
                $text = pq($link_get)->find('.rightcol')->html();
                $title = pq($link_get)->find('.titles a>span')->html();
                $i++;
                $mas[$i] = array('title' => $title, 'img' => $img, 'text' => $text, 'site_url' => $site_url, );
            }

        }
    }
    return $mas;
```

Comment: Будет надежнее искать по MD5 от url.

Comment: Как вариант сделать поле уникальным писать всё и просто отрабатывать ошибки.